# Elements of Programming Interview 5.15 (Random Subset Computation)

Tags: python, algorithm

Algorithm problem:

> Write a program which takes as input a positive integer `n` and size
>   `k <= n`; return a size-k subset of `{0, 1, 2, .. , n -1}`. The subset
>   should be represented as an array. All subsets should be equally
>   likely, and in addition, all permutations of elements of the array
>   should be equally likely. You may assume you have a function which
>   takes as input a nonnegative integer `t` and returns an integer in the
>   set `{0, 1,...,t-1}`.

My original solution to this in pseudocode is as follows:

- Set t = n, and output the result of the random number generator into a `set()` until `set()` has `size(set) == t`. Return `list(set)`

The author solution is as follows:

```
def online_sampling(n, k):
  changed_elements = {}
  for i in range(k):
    rand_idx = random.randrange(i, n)
    rand_idx_mapped = changed_elements.get(rand_idx, rand_idx)
    i_mapped = changed_elements.get(i, i)
    changed_elements[rand_idx] = i_mapped 
    changed_elements[i] = rand_idx_mapped

  return [changed_elements[i] for i in range(k)]
```

I totally understand the author's solution - my question is more about why my solution is incorrect. My guess is that it becomes greatly inefficient as `t` approaches `n`, because in that case, the probability that I need to keep running the random num function until I get a number that isn't in t gets higher and higher. If `t == n`, for the very last element to add to set there is just a `1/n` chance that I get the correct element, and would probabilistically need to run the given `rand()` function `n` times just to get the last item.

Is this the correct reason for why my solution isn't efficient? Is there anything else I'm missing? And how would one describe the time complexity of my solution then? By the above rationale, I believe would be `O(n^2)` since probabilistically need to run `n + n - 1 + n - 2...` times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is (almost) correct.

Firstly, it will run in *O(n log n)* instead of *O(n^2)*, assuming that all operations with set are *O(1)*. Here's why.

The expected time to add the first element to the set is *1 = n/n*.
The expected time to add the second element to the set is *n/(n-1)*, because the probability to randomly choose yet unchosen element is *(n-1)/n*. See [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) for an explanation.
...
For *k*-th element, the expected time is *n/(n-k)*. So for *n* elements the total time is *n/n + n/(n-1) + ... + n/1 = n * (1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n) = n log n*.

Moreover, we can prove by induction that all chosen subsets will be equiprobable.

However, when you do `list(set(...))`, it is not guaranteed the resulting list will contain elements in the same order as you put them into a set. For example, if set is implemented as a binary search tree then the list will always be sorted. So you have to store the list of unique found elements separately.

UPD (@JimMischel): we proved the *average case* running time. There still is a possibility that the algorithm will run indefinitely (for example, if `rand()` always returns `1`).

Comment: Check my reply. I think his answer is completely wrong because his result is not equally likely.

Comment: @Afshin set does not contain duplicates. This, proof by induction: assume that if the set contains k numbers then all subsets are equiprobable. Now, each of remaining n-k numbers may become the k+1-th with equal probability. It proves the induction step. Also note that the claim is true for k=1.

Comment: Your induction is based on result set, and I think is not correct here because problem is selecting from original list with equal chance. Assume we have have no item in set. You can add 1st item with 1/n chance. But after adding 1st item, 2nd item will not be added with same chance, it will be chance of selecting an item from n items which is not 1st item and this chance is not equal to 1/n. so items for resulting set have not selected with equal chance and they will not be equally likely.

Comment: @Afshin On the second step one of the following happens: a) with probability 1/n I select the item already in the set; b) with probability (n-1)/n I select some new item. All n-1 new items are indistinguishable, so for each of them conditional probability (select this particular item | some new item is selected) is 1/(n-1).

Comment: There is the *possibility*, however remote, that the original algorithm is not deterministic, especially as t approaches n. How many random selections does it take to generate all n numbers in the range 1..n? We can compute the *expected* value, and the minimum is n, but the maximum is unknown.

Comment: My probabilities was never good, but I think your conditional probability is wrong. `P(A|B)=P(A intersect B)/P(B)` , isn't it? But what is `P(A intersect B)`, if A is selecting something that is previously selected and B is selecting something new? I think `P(A intersect B)` should be 0 because these sets don't overlap. Chance 1/(n-1) is correct, but it will only happen **if** you remove item that is already selected from original set (this is method that author used) and select among other ones.

Comment: @JimMischel Right, I'll add it to the answer, thanks.

Comment: @Afshin Here `A` is `this particular new element is taken`, and `B` is `some new element is taken`. In particular, A contains B. So, P(A) = 1/n, P(A and B) = 1/n, and P(B) = (n-1)/n. Thus P(A|B) = P(A) * P(B) = 1/(n-1). It holds for every new element.

Comment: I still think there is something wrong here, and maybe I cannot see it correctly and prove it. I think selecting from whole original set creates a situation that algorithms such as Fisher-Yates counter. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov Thanks for your response. Clarifying question: it's not clear to me why, if the expected probability for the second digit generated is (n-1)/n, the expected time is (n) / (n-1). Perhaps I'm missing a fundamental understanding of related probability theory - do you mind expanding on this? (Or pointing me in a helpful direction?)

Comment: @Sunny You're welcome. Consider accepting my answer if it helped you. About your question: if you have a series of independent experiments each of them succeeding with probability *p*, then the expected number of attempts to get a success is *1/p* because this number follows geometric distribution. I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your method has a big problem. You may return duplicate numbers if you random number generator create same number two times isn't it?

If you say `set()` will not keep duplicate numbers, your method has created members of set with different chance. So numbers in your set will not be equally likely.

**Problem with your method is not efficiency, it does not create an equally likely result set.** The author uses a variation of [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) method for creating that subset which will be equally likely.